# Setting QRegExp to QML TextField validator disables Textfield

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a list of regexes to use in my application as singleton so I don't have to write it everywhere , I tried creating qml QtObject but it's not working in qml cause there is no RegExp object in qml and `property var x = /regex/` not working as regex its a string.
I created a cpp class to put my regexes into it:

```
#ifndef UVALIDATORS_H
#define UVALIDATORS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QJSEngine>
class UValidators : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(UValidators)
    Q_PROPERTY(QRegExp time READ time )
public:
    static QObject* instance(QQmlEngine *engine,QJSEngine *scriptEngine){
        Q_UNUSED(engine);
        Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine);
        return new UValidators;
    };
    explicit UValidators(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QRegExp time() const;

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // UVALIDATORS_H
```

for cpp :

```
#include "uvalidators.h"

UValidators::UValidators(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
QRegExp UValidators::time() const{
    QRegExp time;
    time.setPattern("/^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/");
    return time;
}
```

And I register it using :

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<UValidators>("U",1,0,"Validators",&UValidators::instance);
```

And I use it like this :

```
TextField{
            validator:RegExpValidator{ 
              regExp:U.Validators.time
            }
        }
```

Everything is fine application runs but textfield wont let me write anything.
Is there any way to create regexp list in qml or cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is with regex `/^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/` if you want to set pattern to `QRegExp` you should drop `/` from start and end of regex. any way if you know a better solution to this regex issue in qml without cpp let me know!

```
time.setPattern("^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$");
```

Answer (score 3):

If your regex expressions stay at QML level you can simply store them in a shared js file:

```
// Regex.js
var time = /^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/;
```

Usable in any QML file:

```
import "Regex.js" as Regex

TextField {
    validator: RegExpValidator { 
        regExp: Regex.time
    }
}
```

Comment: did you test it? i'll try it soon but problem is in qml there is no variable for regex type so it didnt work for me before, but i didnt test an external js file.

Comment: I didn't test this particular code but I am using this method in multiple projects so I guarantee it is a very simple working solution :-)
But you should also be able to store it in a QML property, I am not sure what your problem is. `property var time = /^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/` should work (`time` being a `RegExp` object directly usable in `RegExpValidator.regExp` property). Note that you can also store a string `property string time = "^...$"` and use it with `regExp: new RegExp(time)`.

Comment: @MahdiKhalili what do you mean by "problem is in qml there is no variable for regex type"? Both `QRegExp` and `QRegularExpression` are supported in QML, you can assign a js regex literal to it or use the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: @GrecKo `property var time = /^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/`  is not working in qml its not a QRegExp its a QString or at least QtCreator says its a QString

Comment: @augre its working with external js file but inside qml is not working

Comment: @augre but this solution has other problems i don't have much control over my Regex pattern what if i wanted to have a dynamic regex?